# angular-chart.js showing black color chart in Firefox, Safari, and IE

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

In Chrome I am able to see the correct color for a line chart but in Firefox, Safari, and IE the chart turns black. Am I missing anything in configuration?

Please find codepen for the same.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGmPEy?editors=1010

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="apingDefaultDesignController">
<canvas id="line"
    class="chart chart-line"
    chart-options="chartOptions"
    chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"
    chart-data="chartData"
    chart-labels="chartLabels"
    chart-colors="chartColors">
  </canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks,
MSK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, this was tough:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLpGyY?editors=1010

You were missing brackets on `$scope.chartData` so it wasn't rendering properly. You need to set it as array of arrays even if you have only one dataset

Try with this:

```
$scope.chartData = [[1,20,3,40,5,60,7]];
```

I guess Safari and Firefox aren't as smart as Chrome is :)